# How do I re-save all users?

Tags: 8, users, batch-operations

I need to re-save about 300 user to initialize geo-coding on their address fields. On /admin/people, I don't see any bulk action that would fit my needs. I have tested the update path-alias but with no luck.

Also, the VBO module for Drupal 8 doesn't offer a solution for users, AFAIK.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how comfortable you are with code. I would suggest writing an update hook in a custom module. Something like:

```
MYMODULE_update_8100(&$sandbox) {
  // On the initial run, set up the update.
  if (empty($sandbox)) {
    // Get all user ids.
    $sandbox['items'] = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
      ->accessCheck(FALSE)
      ->execute();
    $sandbox['max'] = count($sandbox['items']);

    if (!$sandbox['max']) {
      // Prevent division by zero if there are no users.
      $sandbox['#finished'] = 1;
      return;
    }
  }

  $iteration = 0;
  while ($iteration < 25 && $sandbox['items']) {
    $iteration ++;

    // Resave each user.
    \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('user')
      ->load(end($sandbox['items']))
      ->save();

    // Remove the end of the items list when the item has finished 
    // processing.
    array_pop($sandbox['items']);
  }

  // Update the completion status as a number between 0 and 1.
  $sandbox['#finished'] = ($sandbox['max'] - count($sandbox['items']) / $sandbox['max'];
}
```

See [`hook_update_N`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.2.x) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Bamford, i'll give it a try. Time to write my first d8 module... :)

Comment: Good luck have fun!

Comment: The timeout thing looks a bit odd. Actually when you batch process users the right way you don't need to worry about timeouts. That's what the sandbox is for. You need to make your code look like in the following sample which processes users in chunks of 25 users each. https://gorannikolovski.com/blog/batch-processing-and-update-hooks-drupal-8.

Comment: That example assumes that you can process 25 users before the server times out. Mine assumes the server has a timeout of 60 seconds and makes sure to end before then. Each process makes assumptions. My code could be optimized better, to make fewer db requests, but given that updates are only run once, I don't usually stress about making them as fast as possible.

Comment: I'm with @leymannx on this one. The standard pattern in core update hooks is to do a `COUNT()` query (or similar) to initialize, and then load the items in each batch with a `->range()` query. Personally, I think the timeout approach is fragile.

Comment: Both updates make assumptions. Mine assumes that server timeout is more than 55 seconds, and that a task takes less time than the difference between 55 and the server time out. The standard way assumes that a task takes less than 1/25 of the server's timeout interval.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but if anyone is using this, or the link provided by @leymannx to write their own update that does something else, they should realize that processing in small batches will fail if items take too long to process, or if setup takes more time than is budgeted.

Comment: Rules module is an interesting option to consider in your case. If you share more detailed we might be able to help you with it. e.g. do you have to change all accounts at once or having a rule that edits the user account when a user sign-in is a valid option

Comment: @CharlesBamford and leymannx, I tried both suggestions, but i think i am missing something crucial. I was able to create a module with a info.yaml and a resave_users.module (where i tried the scripts) files and I can enable it, but nothing happens. Do i need something else? Is .module the correct file extension?

Comment: Or do I need to define a controller? If so, where do i look it up? Thanks!

Comment: When drupal installs a module, it checks for hook update N and assumes that the installation schema is the same as the schema version of the update and doesn't process any previous updates. The module needs to be enabled first, then the update can be added. It is usually added into a .install file.